# MACPro restarts one second after shutdown if USB Hub is connected - Why?

Tags: macos, mac, usb, mac-pro, shutdown

i have added a USB3.0 PCIe card (Inateck KTU3FR-4P USB 3.0 expresskarte 4 port) to my Mac (MacPro Early 2008, OS X 10.8.4 (12E55))

...with this all is working as it should, no problems with shutdown.

To have better access to the USB3 ports i have now bought an USB3 Hub (Inateck HBU3VL2-4 4 port USB 3.0 Hub without extra current needed).

**And this is what makes me problems.
If i connect the Hub to the Card, and afterwards shutdown my Mac, it restarts itself after 1 second.**

The console log shows some strange info about current and an error *(SetFeature(kUSBFeatureDeviceRemoteWakeup) failed. Error 0xe000404f)*
...

[image]
But the Systeminfo shows well...

[image]

And during working with the mac all is OK. Also if i connect a hdd to the hub, it is working as it should...only shutdown doesn't work if the hub (with or without any device on it) is connected to the card.

Shutdown/restart Log:

[image]

[image]

There is no wake reason...

Any ideas how to fix this are welcome?

Thanks, richard.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment by accident...the question was are you connecting a 4 USB to another 4 USB splitter? Second question was, do you have the remote wake up enabled?

Comment: 1. I connect a 4-port Hub to a 4-port PCIe card...
2. I haven't done anything with remote wakeup...where is this configured?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying one of the points. Could you also supply the information on Wake Up?, Go to Console and type "Wake reason" and look for the time stamp around your shut down. That should tell us what or who is waking it up.

Comment: I think you mean to search in the syslog...there is no wake reson for today...

Comment: Richards-Mac-Pro:~ riko$ syslog | grep "Wake reason"<br/>
Aug 15 11:03:01 Richards-Mac-Pro kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: PWRB EHCI (User)<br/>
Aug 16 09:36:43 Richards-Mac-Pro kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHCI<br/>
Aug 16 13:05:11 Richards-Mac-Pro kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHCI<br/>
Aug 17 10:52:05 Richards-Mac-Pro kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHCI<br/>
Aug 18 11:21:29 Richards-Mac-Pro kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHCI<br/>
Aug 25 14:55:51 Richards-Mac-Pro kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHCI<br/>

Comment: Sorry, dont know how to format this better...linebreaks dont show correctly....but last wake reason was on august...

Comment: **One additional info...there is a power led on the PCIe card, and if the hub is connected this led does continue to light after shutdown...one/two second later the mac startsup again...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating 8 USB connections on a single USB with your set up without additional power supply for the external USB.

That might create some problems in [power management for the host USB](http://www.edn.com/design/communications-networking/4346294/Stealing-USB-port-power) controller in your system.

Once you connect the device to the USB port, the specification imposes limits on current draw.

The host first recognizes any peripheral as a low-power device, which is limited to less than 100 mA of current. (total of 800mA in your case, which is very close to the limit of 900mA):

The peripheral can then ask the host to recognize it as a high-power device through a process called enumeration.

Once enumeration is complete and permission is granted, the peripheral current limitation increases to 500 mA for that device, but remember the internal limit is 900mA for all.

Your second Error (SetFeature(kUSBFeatureDeviceRemoteWakeup) failed!

The USB specification also includes a suspend mode that supports remote wake-up.

This mode limits quiescent current to a total of 500 µA for a low-power device and 2.5 mA for a high-power device; it often requires switches to power down portions of the peripheral's electronics. That would be normal error with 8 USB ports connected, so just try without them, or leave it alone

Why does you computer wakes up!

```
Aug 25 14:55:51 Richards-Mac-Pro kernel[0] <Debug>: Wake reason: EHCI
```

Based on your information for wake reason, the EHCI is the USB host controller that does that. 
One solution would be to used a self powered USB.

To post only the wake reason use the cmd+shift+4 to take a screen shot only of the wake reason.

[image]

Comment: No, as you see this was on august, not today or yesterday...the case there was disconnecting my iPad...in the first post i have added 2 more comments (just if you dont have seen)

Comment: Ok...so if you are right with this power things, it means this device is just not working(at least the shutdown) on a mac and i have to buy a hub which is selfpowered...correct?...is this also why the led continues to light?

Comment: Sorry, crosstalk :) so what is the wake reason for today? That the LED is still on indicates that your system is trying to shut down the USB but did not get confirmation so it goes back to on state waiting for you to turn off any USB devices. Since as you say you have none connected physically, it could be that you unplugging it did not register so it thinks it is still there. To verify that before shut down and after you disconnected the USB device, check you system information for USB to confirm it is shown as disconnected there.

Comment: Today, after i have read your message, i have connected the hub to the card...no additional device...and then shutdown the mac...i will add a answer to insert the syslog of shutdown/restart...please wait...

Comment: **Have added the syslog to my first question...**

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem with your font size, not possible to read. Please use cmd+shift+4 (the number 4) to take a screen shot and post the image (link) I will make it in to a readable image. see example in my answer.

Comment: **Ok.. done, but with rightclick save picture it should be able to read...**

Comment: @Buscar...i think you are right with your first answer about the current, and this hub does not work correctly with my PCIe card...at least on a macpro.... I will go for 4 simple extension cables to connect to my card.... Thank you for your time...